# gnome-panel icons spacing

Tags: 12.10, icons, gnome-classic

I'm using Gnome Classic with no effects because Compiz is slow on my notebook. Everything is fine except panel icons - they are too wide. They look OK with Compiz. How can I make them look the same in Gnome Classic with no effects?

[image: icons]

With Compiz:

[image: compiz on]

Comment: They look OK to me. Can you include a screenshot of how you'd expect them to look, in your question as well?

Comment: My spacing is about 20% of that, I had it like that once and I don't know what I did to fix it, just adding confirmation that this spacing is too large.

Comment: Added screenshot